# I can't import module from other folders

Tags: python

I can't import all of functions from own module in other directory

```
my project structure:

/
|-code
    |-db_orm
        |-__init__.py
        |-db_interface.py
    |-streamlit
        |-pages
            |-subpage1.py
            |-subpage2.py
        |-main.py
```

i want to add functions from `db_interface.py` module into `subpage1.py` & `subpage2.py` file with this code:

```py
from db_orm.db_interface import *
```

but i can't do it ! 
i am using `VS Code` and `python 3.9.13` 
thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd advice you to now use the * operator to import everything and import only the functions that you use for each of the files because it is prone to annoying errors.

Anyway, you can try `from code.db_orm.db_interface import *`. If that doesn't work I would highly suggest for you to look at `poetry` a python packaging and dependency management. It will make the project a package and imports will be a lot easier to do with it.

Comment: @Roy thanks for your advices & `poetry` package but your suggestion code `from code.db_orm.db_interface import *` not work for me ! anyway thanks

Comment: Yea, i'd reckon it wouldn't work. Just go for poetry once you understand it you wouldn't start any other python project without it.

Comment: @Roy yeah sure, I'm starting to read the `poetry` document soon

Answer (score 0):

A manual option to import modules from other directories is `SourceFileLoader`.
Not following the `from` syntax, but a quick solution for e.g. brief trials:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

db_interface = SourceFileLoader("db_interface",">YourSystemPath</db_interface.py").load_module()

# call
db_interface.foo()  # foo being a function in db_interface
```

Note: `>YourSystemPath<` can be absolute or relative.

---

If you want to keep the calls only on the functions you could add further functions in between:

```
def foo():
    db_interface.foo()


foo()
```

Again that will get messy for larger projects but is a quick workaround.